# Score points in images with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, canvas

I have an image and would like to set it fixed points that clicking, appeared one modal. How to do this with jquery, html5 canvas? I would not want to use flash.

I want to do is similar to Google Maps but the image is fixed and also points, these points would be visible in the image, when you click on these points, I would open a modal. The fear is that when the user changes the browser or re-size it, these points come out of the place. The idea is that the points fit the screen, regardless of size.

Could someone give me at least a North do this.

note:Have not tried anything with Flash always worked and now I'm coming to html5, css3, jquery.Apenas not know where to start to solve this problem.

Comment: Try recording the click coordinates relative to the image size making sure that the image always has the same fixed-pixel size.

Comment: You mention Flash.  If you know Flash well, you can create your swf using Flash and then use a conversion program called Zoe to create a spritesheet from your swf.  Then there's a canvas library called EaselJS that can display the images on that spritesheet. Check out Zoe here: http://www.fabiobiondi.com/blog/2012/08/createjs-zoe-create-spritesheets-in-adobe-flash-for-easeljs/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at frameworks like paperjs or kineticjs. These frameworks extend the functionality of html5 canvas and make your live a lot easier. Both frameworks are well documented and have some nice examples.